# Java GUI stumped. Only one display in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am trying to create `Jframe` that houses three `JPanels`. I have extended `JPanel` so that each time it may be passed a color and a diameter. The end result being a `JFrame` that has 1 red, 1 yellow and 1 green `stoplightpanel`. I plan on adding an `ActionListener` to these panels which is why it is designed this way. It is not working because currently, I only can see the yellow panel.

Fair warning this is for a class. So I have tried every configuration I can think of and I still only see one instance of my subclass present in my `Jframe`. If anyone can point out the obvious I would be appreciated. Oddly enough only my yellow light is displayed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class TrafficLight3 extends JFrame {

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        TrafficLight3 tl = new TrafficLight3 ( );
    }

    // Constructor 
    public TrafficLight3( ) {

        setTitle( "Traffic Light" );
        setSize ( 200, 400 );
        setLocation ( 200, 200 );
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        StopLightPanel red = new StopLightPanel( 100, Color.RED );

        // add stoplight panel's to JFrame's default border layout. 
        add( red, BorderLayout.NORTH );

        StopLightPanel yellow = new StopLightPanel( 100, Color.YELLOW );
        add( yellow, BorderLayout.CENTER );        

        StopLightPanel green = new StopLightPanel( 100, Color.GREEN );
        add ( green, BorderLayout.SOUTH );        

        setVisible( true );
    }
    class StopLightPanel extends JPanel {

        private int diameter;
        private Color color;

        public StopLightPanel ( int d, Color c) {

             diameter = d;
            color = c;
        }

        public void paintComponent ( Graphics g ) {

            g.setColor ( color );
            g.fillOval ( 50, 25, diameter, diameter );
       }
     }  
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide us with more information? Namely: 1) What you're trying to accomplish, 2) What isn't working. I'll remove my downvote when you do.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for any confusion, I've updated it, but do let me know if there isn't enough clarity. I am asking for help, so I'd like to make it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- Ensure that your code runs in [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

2- @Flight2039 is correct, it seems that `BorderLayout` where location is not the CENTER uses `preferredSize` to determinate the size. So you could override `getPreferredSize()`

3- When you override `paintComponent(..)` you have to call `super.paintComponent(..)` to follow painting method chaining. More information [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

4- Add @Override annotation always this will check at compile time for example if you make some typo overriding the method.

See this runnable example, i used gridLayout with one column and three rows.

```
package test2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TrafficLight3 {

    private JPanel redPanel;
    private JPanel yellowPanel;
    private JPanel greenPanel;

    // Constructor
    public TrafficLight3() {        
        redPanel = new StopLightPanel(100, Color.RED);
        yellowPanel = new StopLightPanel(100, Color.YELLOW);
        greenPanel = new StopLightPanel(100, Color.GREEN);
    }

    private static class StopLightPanel extends JPanel {
        private int diameter;
        private Color color;

        public StopLightPanel(int d, Color c) {
            diameter = d;
            color = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(50, 25, diameter, diameter);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            int x = diameter*2;
            return new Dimension(x,x);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic Light");
        frame.setSize(200,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(Boolean.TRUE);
        TrafficLight3 example = new TrafficLight3();
        frame.add(example.redPanel);
        frame.add(example.yellowPanel);
        frame.add(example.greenPanel);
        // Display the window.      
        frame.setVisible(Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the output..

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you were correct, both you and the poster below were a great help. I switched to grid layout and add override annotations. I've noted the invoke later as well and will implement it in any non class assignments.

Comment: @user2557015 nice to help, consider accepting the answer with the green mark. And as a side note your inner class, should be a static nested class cause that class doesn't belongs to an instance of the top class.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `getPreferredSize()` for your custom JPanels so that layout managers know how big to make them. The center position will size your panels to use all the available space, but the other positions will not.  See this example which also removes your `setSize()` and `setLocation()` as well and replaces it with a call to pack().

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TrafficLight3 extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TrafficLight3 tl = new TrafficLight3();

        }

    });
    }

    // Constructor
    public TrafficLight3() {

        setTitle("Traffic Light");
        // setSize(200, 400);
        // setLocation(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        StopLightPanel red = new StopLightPanel(100, Color.RED);

        // add stoplight panel's to JFrame's default border layout.
        add(red, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        StopLightPanel yellow = new StopLightPanel(100, Color.YELLOW);
        add(yellow, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        StopLightPanel green = new StopLightPanel(100, Color.GREEN);
        add(green, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class StopLightPanel extends JPanel {

        private int diameter;
        private Color color;

        public StopLightPanel(int d, Color c) {

            diameter = d;
            color = c;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(50, 25, diameter, diameter);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 133);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you this is pretty helpful. I am working on setting the preferred sizes which has made a difference. I see the border layout has preferred sizes, so overriding this is necessary. I am not sure "setLocationRelative (null) " does yet but I can google it. I assume sets this so that it re-sizes correctly when the window is. Anyway thanks for the tip I am on the right track now.

Comment: setLocationRelativeTo(null) positions the window in the center of the screen .

Comment: ah, I will use this often then thank you. when I get the ability to upvote I will send some your way.

Comment: Don't forget to add the required call to super.paintComponent

Comment: and also ensure that code runs in `EDT` using `EventQueue.invokeLater(..)` then there you will win my +1, `setLocationByPlattform`

Comment: Two good points I forgot to add to my answer when copying OPs code.

Comment: Arg. I was using a test class in my IDE and forgot to change it back to OPs class.

Comment: now is right, just remember to use @ username to notify the comment ;) @MadProgrammer doesn't read you